# Java in Android, Help on connecting to a wifi network, and trying to reconnect if unsuccessful

Tags: java, android, networking, network-programming, wifi

I'm implementing a method that if unusuccessful in connecting to a wifi network, it tries to reconnect by using an alert dialog, here is the code I have so far

```
public boolean autoConnect() {
      String networkSSID = "xxxxx";
      boolean connected = false;
      WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();

      conf.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";
      conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
      WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
      wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);
      wifiManager.startScan();
      List<ScanResult> list = wifiManager.getScanResults();
      AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(CarNannyv3Activity.this).create();
      alertDialog.setTitle("xxxxxxxx Not Available");  
      alertDialog.setMessage("Please make sure xxxxxx is turned on ");  
      alertDialog.setButton("Reconnect", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                autoConnect();
                dialog.dismiss();


            } });
      for( ScanResult i : list ) {
          if(i.SSID.equals("\"" + networkSSID + "\"")) {

               //wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
               wifiManager.reconnect();               
               return connected = true;


          }else{

                alertDialog.show();
          }
       } 
      return connected;
  }
```

I get one of two things, it either endless loops the reconnect dialog, or it never shows at all, please shed me some light on what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Your erratic looping has to do with `autoConnect();` calling itself. You're remaking the method every time the user chooses to reconnect. Then **if** that new method call finishes, you have a bunch more that need to finish. Generally, stay away from recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this, its working in my case ::

```
        WifiManager notif_manager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        List<ScanResult> scan_list = notif_manager.getScanResults();
        for (ScanResult scan_ap : scan_list) 
        {
            if (scan_ap.SSID.equals("\"" + networkSSID + "\"")) 
            {

            /* Create a WifiConfig */
                WifiConfiguration eliteAp = new WifiConfiguration();

                /* AP Name */
                eliteAp.SSID = "\"" + ssidString + "\"";

                /* Priority */
                eliteAp.priority = 40;

                /* Enable Hidden SSID */
                eliteAp.hiddenSSID = false;
                .
                .
                .
                .
                .
                .       
                eliteAp.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
                int res = wifi_manager.addNetwork(eliteAp);
                boolean d = wifi_manager.enableNetwork(res, true);
                break;

            }
        }
```

Comment: i used the above code for creating eap configuration,and its really working well..... so may be it will help u too.